# Flattening array

Tags: php

I have a function which changes an array into the html list (ol/ul). The depth of the array is passed as an argument.

I wanted to do this in just a single function.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) {
   foreach($list_array as $li) {
      if(! is_array($li))
      {
         $str .= '<li>' . $li . '</li>';
      }
   }
}
```

This code gives me the first dimension of the array. I'd like to flatten this array every time the `$i` increments.

Do you have any suggestions that could be helpful?

And yes, I'm aware of `array_walk_recursive()`, object iterators etc...I'd like to know if there's a simple way to do this task without using any ot those. I can't come up with anything.

And no, this is not any university project where I'm not allowed to use iterators etc.

EDIT:

```
print_list(array(
   'some first element',
   'some second element',
   array(
      'nested element',
      'another nested element',
      array(
         'something else'
      )
   )
));
```

should output something like:

```
<ul>
   <li>some first element</li>
   <li>some second element</li>
   <ul>
      <li>nested element</li>
      <li>another nested element</li> // etc
```

Comment: why do you not want to use those? Those are there to make it simple...

Comment: So you want to print all the 1st level elements, then all the 2nd level elements? or do you want to put the 2nd level elements *with* their corresponding 1st level element?

Comment: I want to print all the 1st lst level elements, and then 2nd elements etc.

Comment: Maybe you can use recursion and call the function you already have? `if(is_array($li)) { print_list($li); } else { $str .= ... }`.

Comment: It would be easy. I can't use recursion because at the beginning and the end of the function I do some initializations that can't be repeated during recursion.

Comment: Provide a sample of what you have in `$list_array`?

Comment: @user2203484 Can't you refactor the bit that does the initialization into another method, which you call before the printing?

Comment: I could just create print_list() private method, and two public ul() and ol() methods. That would do the thing...well, if this is indeed the best solution, then I guess that's the only way I have left.

Comment: If you had some time to provide me some examples with iterators/array_walk_recursive()/or any of those, I would be vary glad - I have to finally understand how to use them...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be "flattening", which means converting from nested to a single level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably easiest to accomplish using recursion:

```
function print_list($array){
    echo '<ul>';
    // examine every value in the array
    // (including values that may also be arrays)
    for($array as $val){
        if(is_array($val){
            // when we discover the value is, in fact, an array
            // print it as if it were the top-level array using
            // this function
            print_list($val);
        }else{
            // if this is a regular value, print it as a list item
            echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

If you want to do indentation, you could define a depth tracking parameter and a co-routine (`print_list_internal($array, $depth)`) or just add a default parameter (`print_list($array,$depth=0)`) and then print a number of spaces in front of anything depending on `$depth`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function print_list($array) {
  echo '<ul>';
  // First print all top-level elements
  foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!is_array($val)) {
      echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
    }
  }
  // Then recurse into all the sub-arrays
  foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      print_list($val);
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```